# I want to make the delete button functional in this javascript program. What is the syntax for the function and where does it go? .js only

Tags: javascript

How to create the delete function for an array. What is the syntax to make the function and where does it go in the code?

Beginning to get frustrated have to much time invested to give up.

```
var userNames = [""];
/*******************************/                   
//init() function

function init()
{
var myButton = document.getElementById("btnSubmit");            
myButton.onclick = registerName;
}           
onload = init;          
/********************************************/          
function registerName()     
{
var newName = document.getElementById("txtName").value.toString();

var message = "";

var result = document.getElementById("result");         
var success = false;            
if (newName == "")
{
alert("Please, enter a Username");          
return false;
}

for (var i = 0; i < userNames.length; i++)
{           
    if (userNames[i] == newName)
    {
    message = "Sorry, the Username " + userNames[i] + " already exists.  Try                              again";              

    result.innerHTML = message;

    success = false;

    //stop further program execution

    return false;
    }

    else
    {
    message = "Great, you've successfully registered with us as " + newName;

    result.innerHTML = message;

    success = true;
    }

}

if (success)
{
userNames.push(newName);
}

userNames.sort(); 

var myTable = "<table><tr><td>NAME</td>";
myTable+= "<td>ACTION</td></tr>"; 
myTable+= "<tr><td>---------------</td>";
myTable+= "<td>---------------</td></tr>";

for (var i=0; i< userNames.length; i++)
    {
    myTable+="<tr>";
    userNames[i] = userNames[i].toString();
    myTable+="<td>" + userNames[i] + "</td>";
        myTable+="<td>" + "<button> Delete </button>" + "</td></tr>"; //NEED TO REPLACE "DELETE" WITH YOUR DELETE BUTTON 
    }  
    myTable+="</table>";

//OUTPUT THE ENTIRE TABLE AS AN ELEMENT FOR HTML
document.getElementById('tablePrint').innerHTML = myTable;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the html of a button:

```
<input type='button' value='delete' />
```

So you could use this in your javascript:

```
myTable+="<td><input type='button' value='delete' /></td></tr>";
```

Another (better) way to create a button is to create a DOM element and add it to the DOM

```
var btn = document.createElement("button");
var tn = document.createTextNode("delete");
btn.appendChild(tn);
document.getElementById("parent").appendChild(btn);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bqhemmg2/) here.

Comment: Thank you for the assistance. Where would DOM go in my code? When I place it in the code my output go's away.

Comment: Where would the DOM go in my code. It eliminates my output almost wherever I put it.

Comment: The DOM code would need some more work to fit in your code. You will not just be able to plug it in.

Comment: What would I need to do to it?

Comment: You would need to change the way you build your table and all the rows. i.e. document.createElement("table") then create a row, then create cell, then create a button. Append the button to the cell, append the cell to the row, append the row to the table.

Comment: I am going to attempt it and again it is appeciated.

Comment: I have not been able to get it to work correctly. I am at a loss. Any help!

Comment: Did my first solution not work? `myTable+="<td><input type='button' value='delete' /></td></tr>"; `